# Resize image to equal width and height while uploading in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to automatically resize the image while uploading by using this function:

```
function ak_img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext) {
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);
    $scale_ratio = $w_orig / $h_orig;
    if (($w / $h) > $scale_ratio) {
           $w = $h * $scale_ratio;
    } else {
           $h = $w / $scale_ratio;
    }
    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){ 
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else { 
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    // imagecopyresampled(dst_img, src_img, dst_x, dst_y, src_x, src_y, dst_w, dst_h, src_w, src_h)
    imagecopyresampled($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy, 80);
}
```

and then :

```
$target_file = "img/".$admit_roll.".".$ext;
$resized_file = "img/".$admit_roll.".".$ext;
$wmax = 200;
$hmax = 200;
ak_img_resize($target_file, $resized_file, $wmax, $hmax, $ext);
```

But this isn't returning a square sized-image even when `$wmax` abd `$hmax` are same. How should make it return a square size image ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the function `imagecopyresized()` to resize it:

```php
  function img_resize($target, $newcopy, $w, $h, $ext){
    list($w_orig, $h_orig) = getimagesize($target);

    $img = "";
    $ext = strtolower($ext);
    if ($ext == "gif"){
      $img = imagecreatefromgif($target);
    } else if($ext =="png"){
      $img = imagecreatefrompng($target);
    } else {
      $img = imagecreatefromjpeg($target);
    }
    $tci = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
    imagecopyresized($tci, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w_orig, $h_orig);
    imagejpeg($tci, $newcopy);
  }
```

With this function you don't have to care about aspect ratio, the [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php) does for you.

**Edit:** You can replace the function `imagecopyresized()`with `imagecopyresampled()`, it will do the same thing, although with more quality, but using more cpu time

Answer (score 1):

Image manipulation is complex. You can learn to do it yourself, that's fun and sometimes useful. But it also tedious as you need to learn all the problems that others already solved.

Another alternative is to use one of the [libraries](https://packagist.org/search/?q=image) that make it easy for you to achieve this.

For example: [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/)

Take a look how its easier to [fit image into a frame](http://image.intervention.io/api/fit).

```
// open file a image resource
$img = Image::make('public/foo.jpg');

// crop the best fitting 5:3 (600x360) ratio and resize to 600x360 pixel
$img->fit(600, 360);

// crop the best fitting 1:1 ratio (200x200) and resize to 200x200 pixel
$img->fit(200);

// add callback functionality to retain maximal original image size
$img->fit(800, 600, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->upsize();
});
```